# Powershell delete files only from directory

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to delete all files (but not directories) in D:\MyTemp folder, I've tried:

```
Remove-Item "D:\MyTemp"
Remove-Item "D:\MyTemp\*"
```

However, when I check, all the files are still there.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-ChildItem *.* -recurse | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
```

Found it here:
https://superuser.com/questions/150748/have-powershell-get-childitem-return-files-only

To delete all files in the specified directory only (ignoring sub-dirs):

```
Remove-Item "D:\MyTemp\*.*" | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
```

Comment: This only lists file in the current directory

Comment: My bad, wasn't sure if you wanted to do recurse. I'll edit the original. You can just add -recurse to the Get-ChildItem command

Comment: This works (only delete files from specified directory, ignoring sub-dirs): Remove-Item "D:\MyTemp\\*.*" | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }

Comment: That's great. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Sorry btw SteB, I just noticed I forgot to include the Remove-Item. It's going to be a long day wow!

Comment: NB: running `update-help` then `help remove-item -examples` you'll see that `remove-item`'s `-recurse` parameter is faulty; hence the need to use `get-childitem` to take advantage of that parameter.

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, instead I needed:

```
Get-Childitem -File | Foreach-Object {Remove-Item $_.FullName}
```

To include folders as well as files, add `-Recurse`:

```
Get-Childitem -File -Recurse | Foreach-Object {Remove-Item $_.FullName}
```

Comment: This deletes files from subdirectories as well - possibly not what the OP intended...

Comment: This answer should be accepted one. I choose you!

Answer (score 4):

You were nearly there, you just needed:

```
Remove-Item "D:\MyTemp\*.*"
```

Answer (score 1):

@bourne almost had it:

```
Get-ChildItem *.* -recurse | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | remove-item
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/304310)

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't provide an answer? What does it do? It is the only complete answer on the page.

Comment: It's not a self-sufficient answer.  To the point in your response it's a correction to another answer and should be included as a comment.

Comment: sorry, I guess you don't understand powershell. Just because I refer to another answer, it doesn't make mine any less "self-sufficient",

Comment: you might want to explain the issue with the other answer, making it a command.
Otherwise you might want to explain what your Powershell command does

Comment: this is a lot of back and forth over nothing. I was just trying to be helpful. @Dennis, your comment isn't comprehensible, so I can't answer it. If this site isn't interested in helpful answers, I apologize and will go to a "read only" mode.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I'm aware of would be the following (obviously navigate to the directory you want to empty files from):

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Remove-Item
```

I'm not sure if this requires a minimum version but I'm pretty sure this has worked for a long time.